# use jq to extract ranking from a list

Tags: json, command-line, jq

I want to extract a ranking from a list of elements inside a json object whose order shows the position of the item in the respective category. That should be done by using only command line tools.

E.g.
I have a file with these 2 samples (each json object should be one-line but parsed with indentation here for readability ) :

```json
{
    "category":"triathlon",
    "athletes_list":[
        {
            "athlete_name": "Ubain Solt"
        }
        ,
        {
        "athlete_name": "Jon Snow"
        }
        ,
        {
        "athlete_name": "Mickey Mouse"
        }
    ]

}
{
    "category":"swimming",
    "athletes_list":[
        {
        "athlete_name": "Picheal Phelms"
        },
        {
        "athlete_name":"Lacky Kedetie"
        }
    ]
}
```

and want as output:

```json
{"a":"Ubain Solt", "r":0, "c":"triathlon"}
{"a":"Jon Snow", "r":1, "c":"triathlon"}
{"a": "Mickey Mouse", "r":2, "c":"triathlon"}
{"a": "Picheal Phelms", "r":0, "c":"swimming"}
{"a": "Lacky Kedetie", "r":1, "c":"swimming"}
```

Requirements are to use jq and solution must be 1-liner.

Answer (score 1):

```
jq -s '.[] | .category as $c | .athletes_list | to_entries[] | ({ a: .value.athlete_name, r: .key, c: $c })' triathlon swimming
```

Will produce:

```json
{
  "a": "Ubain Solt",
  "r": 0,
  "c": "triathlon"
}
{
  "a": "Jon Snow",
  "r": 1,
  "c": "triathlon"
}
{
  "a": "Mickey Mouse",
  "r": 2,
  "c": "triathlon"
}
{
  "a": "Picheal Phelms",
  "r": 0,
  "c": "swimming"
}
{
  "a": "Lacky Kedetie",
  "r": 1,
  "c": "swimming"
}
```

The 'trick' is to use `to_entries` so we can use `.key` as the 'index'.